# Updating words throughout document

Tags: tables, automation

In my job we deliver several of hundred physical assemblies per project - typically to offshore platforms in Nordsjøen - each one has a corresponding tag (and also other metadata such as item description and serial number).

A typical tag for an assembly may be "42MV43523" and is unique and considered to be the "adress" of the equipment on an offshore platform.

However, when writing all necessary technical documentation for the project, I often end up with hundreds of pages where I need tag references (with the full tag, not a (1) referring to some list). Although documents often are formatted the same, I need to

1. Put these tags into free text in several places (always the same places)
2. Put these tags into tables where descriptions comes on the same line, e.g.

|42Mv43523|Supplier name|Item Description|

|42Mv43558|Supplier name|Item Description|

(...)

The problem is that updating these documents throughout becomes a heavy ad hoc job which takes up a lot of my time (between 10 - 20 hours a week). Also, quite often I need to send these documents in for temporary approval without the tag being decided which makes it even worse.

What I am hoping for is to create one or two master documents where I can write the tags and corresponding metadata for each project, and where the tags and metadata can be updated throughout the document both in tables and in free text (for free text, metadata is not necessary).

Hope this is sufficient information. This is a substantial problem for our company, and many others in the Norwegian oil industry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Just out of curiousity... is a price tag attached to a solution to your problem? `:p`

Comment: An MWE (minimum working example), showing us the "hard way" of doing it, might help to illustrate your needs more fully.  For example, does a document have any number of assemblies referenced, or does a document just reference a single assembly many times?

Comment: If I did understand the problem correctly then I would put the informations in a bib-file and then use biblatex and define suitable \cite-commands (e.g. \citetag, \citesupplier, \citedesc) to get the informations in the documents.

Comment: Thank you, I will read through it and see if I can make a better post. 

No, there is no price tag attached to this, but I could see how it might appear this way from the post ;) It's just a lot of frustration doing this type of work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I hope I understood your question correctly. And as @StevenB.Segletes suggested, it is _always_ good to put together a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates  the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `datatool` pacakge, or use `csname`s as shown here:

1. Create a separate file which contains a few macros and all your tags along with the extended information, which I call `MyTags.tex` in the MWE below:

   ```
   \DefineTag{42Mv43523}{Supplier name 43523}{Item Description 43523}
   \DefineTag{42Mv43558}{Supplier name 43558}{Item Description 43558}
   ```
2. Then `\input` this file as:

   ```
   \input{MyTags.tex}
   ```

   in which case only the tag label is displayed, or as

   ```
   \def\JustUseTag{}
   \input{MyTags.tex}
   ```

   in which case the *tag name*, *supplier name*, and *item description* is displayed.
3. Then, to access the information in your file you use:

   ```
   \UseTag{42Mv43523}

   \UseTag{42Mv43558}
   ```

The output with just `\input{MyTags.tex}` is:

[image]

but with the `\def\JustUseTag{}` just *before* the `\input{MyTags.tex}` is:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) was used just to be able to package the MWE below. It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{MyTags.tex}
    \newcommand*{\DefineTag}[3]{%
        % #1 = tag name
        % #2 = supplier name
        % #3 = item description
        \global\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1TagOnly\endcsname{#1}%
        \global\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1Expanded\endcsname{#1 #2 #3}%
    }%

    \newcommand{\UseTagOnly}[1]{\expandafter\csname#1TagOnly\endcsname}
    \newcommand{\UseTagExpanded}[1]{\expandafter\csname#1Expanded\endcsname}

    \ifdefined\JustUseTag
        \newcommand{\UseTag}[1]{\UseTagOnly{#1}}
    \else
        \newcommand{\UseTag}[1]{\UseTagExpanded{#1}}
    \fi

    \DefineTag{42Mv43523}{Supplier name 43523}{Item Description 43523}
    \DefineTag{42Mv43558}{Supplier name 43558}{Item Description 43558}
\end{filecontents*}



%\def\JustUseTag{}% <--- Un-comment to obtain the additional meta data associated with the tag
\input{MyTags.tex}


\begin{document}

    \UseTag{42Mv43523}

    \UseTag{42Mv43558}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question (a) how familiar you are with LaTeX, and (b) why LaTeX must be used at all for this process (it sounds like a job for database software).  In any case, to give you a sense of what very elementary LaTeX is capable of, see below.  Other more experienced users can suggest more efficient code for when the document gets much longer and the tags pile up.  (And hello from Jubail.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tagone}{42MV43523}
\newcommand{\tagtwo}{42MV43558}

The \tagone{} was signed for upon arrival, blah blah blah...

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Item & Supplier Name & Description\\
\hline
\tagone{} & Bob's House of Petrochemicals & vat of caustic stuff\\
\tagtwo{} & Bits-R-Us & earth-crust-penetrating drill bit\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```